# Buildcontext in backgroundtask in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-workmanager

I want to show periodic notification using workmanager.I need context to navigate when user tap on notification but context is not available in background task.How to solve this issue.I have passed the context as inputData to workmanager but gives **String** is not  subtype of **BuildContext.**

```
 Workmanager().registerPeriodicTask("periodicTaskId", "periodicTaskName",
        inputData: Map.from({"context": context.toString()}),
        frequency: const Duration(minutes: 15));



@pragma('vm-entry-point')
dispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((taskName, inputData) async {
    try {
      
      print(inputData.toString());
       BuildContext context = inputData!['context'];

      await ShowNotificationClass().showNotification(context);

      
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}
```

Comment: You can just remove .toString() from inputData

Comment: inputdata only supports int,bool,list,string and double

Comment: You passed Map as an inputData in your code, so I assume that you can also do like this inputData: Map<String, dynamic>.from({'context' : context});

Comment: Exception has occurred.
_Exception (Exception: argument context has wrong type. WorkManager supports only int, bool, double, String and their list)

Comment: Oh, I see. I don't think there is a way to convert context.toString() to the actual BuildContext. Besides, context.toString() does not contain all the information of the BuildContext object itself.